# Защита блока комментариев и прочая безопасность

Tags: php

Как собственно защитить свои комментарии? Как узнать, что это обычный пользователь прислал комментарий или кто-то через curl запустил скрипт? Какие виды защит существуют для подобных задач? И какая из них самая лучшая? ведь хабр, ютуб и другие многие сервисы защищают же как-то, притом, что там диалоги, люди быстро общаются между собой...

Comment: От кого/чего защищаетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что речь идет о защите от спама.

Начнём с того, что Хабр - совершенно особый сайт, которому в принципе не нужно контролировать автопостинг.

Если же говорить о сайтах типа Ютуба - то появление там спама неизбежно, и защиты никакой не существует. Капча, заметим, защищает только от ботов, но от толпы индусов или ольгинской саранчи технические средства бессильны. Если же ставится задача закрыться именно от "curl"-а - то капча вполне подойдет.

Как паллиатив можно рассматривать системы типа Akismet-а, но против целенаправленного спама они защитить не могут.

Если особо не запариваться, то можно тупо поставить капчу, или даже Некапчу от мейл.ру.

Если запариваться, то на маленьком сайте, под который не будут писать специальный автопостер, можно очень малой кровью на 100% закрыться от автопоста.

Ну а на больших сайтах использовать хороших математиков и ститистические алгоритмы.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос "какая лучшая" защита - из разряда "что вкуснее: торт или колбаса?". Все зависит от ситуации. Что можно сделать:

1. Модерация. Проверять всё, что пишут пользователи перед (или после) публикацией комментария (минус этого варианта - трудоемкость при большом потоке спама);
2. Подсчет/ограничение частоты комментирования (с последующими банами по IP/логину/почте... или запросу капчи);
3. Выявление контрольных слов или другого контента (ссылок, тегов и т. д.);
4. Ограничение по диапазонам IP (например если явно русскоязычная аудитория и большой поток спама - можно убрать из разрешенных Африку, Азию и Америку);
5. Ранжирование пользователей на доверенных/недоверенных;
6. (чуть не забыл) Сделать страницы неинтересными для спаммеров. Например убрать их из индекса сайта (если это возможно).

Естественно это всё можно применять в любых сочетаниях. Также в качестве дополнительной меры можно проверять наличие у клиента JavaScript'а. Если сильно заморочиться, что можно даже собирать события нажатия клавиш и по их наличию, а также временным промежуткам между ними принимать решение, но это уже наверное перебор

Comment: все понятно..вот 3 пункт не очень. что значит "Выявление контрольных слов" ? имеете ввиду, c использование js?

Comment: Не об этом речь. В спам-комментариях чаще встречаются некоторые слова по сравнению с не спамом. При обнаружении этих слов можно, например, переводить комментарий в режим премодерации

Comment: Например что там сейчас спамят в почте "ликвидация", "продажи", "рассылки" и т. д.